# How to access data from sql server 2008 table of a specific date in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, date

In my window application I want to show records held between two dates. I used datepicker to select dates. In sql server 2008 table I used data type [date] to store date. My problem is that it is not working properly to catch the first date, it catches next date to which I select. I used following code :

```
cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("date1", dateTimePicker4.Value);
cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("date2", dateTimePicker5.Value);
```

[image]

and when I try this :

```
cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("date1", dateTimePicker4.Value.AddDays(-1));
cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("date2", dateTimePicker5.Value);
```

Result-

[image]

my complete code

```
cmd10 = new SqlCommand("select a_id,commtyp,convert(varchar(10),date,105),comm,primm,c_id,agent from comm where a_id= '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND  date >= @date1  AND date <=  @date2 ", agr);
            cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-1));
            cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dateTimePicker2.Value);
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd10);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "comm");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "comm";                
            checkBox2.Checked = false;
            groupBox15.Show();
            cmd10.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: +1 for use of parameters

Comment: Please update your post to show your actual query and replace `dateTimePicker5.Value` (and others) with explicit `new DateTime(2012, 07, 19)` so it is clear what value is and what you expect.

Comment: This may be because there's time component attached to the date and your database doesn't have time.

Comment: Try using `dateTimePicker4.Value.Date` - this is the **date-only** part (without the time)

Answer (score 1):

You are using value property from datepicker and it's giving you date with seconds and milliseconds. You have to get the actual datepart from it's value.

try this

```
dateTimePicker4.Value.Date
```

instead of

```
dateTimePicker4.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

you are taking datetime picker and in query may be you are taking from and to dates as datetime.

pleases convert @from and @to datetime in to date as

```
  cast(@From as date)
  cast(@To as date)
```

and then put into condition, it may resolve your problem..